# How to include Python package in py2exe exe

Tags: python, py2exe

While trying to convert multiple .py files into an exe file with py2exe I get the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ParentWindow.py", line 7, in

The mentioned 'FileAnalysers1' is the python package that contains the .py scripts. How to I include the whole package in the exe?

Comment: Please add your current setup.py script.

Answer (score 0):

have a read of [this tutorial](http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/python/pkg_resources-with-py2exe.html) as provided in the answer of the SO question [how to include packages file, py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062797/how-to-include-packages-file-py2exe)

Comment: Does this method work for including the ssl library with an executable?